# Regular expression comparison

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0

I want to check whether my  string variable contain the particular regular expression pattern or not

> xxx-xx-x

(x is numerical value) using c#. If it contains then I need to return true or false.

Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue..

Comment: Could you show us what you've tried so far please?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "contains"? "123" contains "2", right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the returned value by `Regex.IsMatch()`.

```
Regex regex = new Regex("[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]");

bool containsPattern = regex.IsMatch(stringToVerify);
```

Comment: you would also match `111-22-345` or `111-22-3-33`

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ Yes there is an ambiguity in "contain the particular regular expression".

Answer (score 0):

This is the regex you are looking for

```
\b\d{3}-\d{2}-\d\b
```

`\b` is a boundary..If you don't use it,you would also match `111-22-345` or `111-22-3-33` which i guess you don't want to match

Comment: But it will also reject `_111-22-3_` or `ABD111-22-3 xyz`.

Comment: @nhahtdh nice point..but i guess he needs to clarify on that..

Answer (score -2):

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public static bool ControlRegex(string input)
{
   Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

   if (match.Success)
   {
     return true;
   }
}
```

You can try something like this... You have to put correct regular expression to secend parametre of Regex.Match...

You can find the correct regex with a regex program. For example "RegEx TestBed" you can download it from here; http://regextestbed.codeplex.com/releases/view/60833 with this program, you put your text in text area, and in pattern area you try to find correct regex. And below, in the the list area, and program shows you the matches according your regex, so you can try and find your correct regex...

Comment: I didn't down vote this, but I suspect it was down voted because it does not present a regex that fulfills the requirement. The part of returning true/false is there, but I get the idea the OP needed a proper regex, too.

Comment: I see, you can find the correct regex with a regex program. For example "RegEx TestBed" you can download it from here; http://regextestbed.codeplex.com/releases/view/60833 with this program, you put your text in text area, and in pattern area you try your regex. And below the list area, it shows you the matches so you can try and find your correct regex...